# excel formula using a variable with a range of values

Tags: excel

So I have a formula with a single variable   = 1-h/145442  where the value h needs to be analyzed from values of 0 up to 36000  and display the answer.  How do I do this in excel P.S. I am not good with excel please be clear thanks, Josh

Answer (score 0):

Since these are basic functions of spreadsheets this works with every spreadsheet program, I know of OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc and of Excel, and of course Lotus 1-2-3, the mother of spreadsheets.

In A1 type 0, in A2 1.

Select A1. In the name field combo, type in `a1..a36001 <Enter>` (to select that range).

Menu Edit / Fill / Series. You should have filled the selected range with the values from 0 to 36000.

In B1 enter

```
=1-A1/145442 <Enter>.
```

In name field combo, enter `B1..B36001` to select that range.

Press `<Ctrl+U>` to fill the range with the formula. Excel will increment the row number and treat the column letter as static (B2: =1-A2/145442, B3: =1-A3/145442, ...).

This should be it. If something does not work, you need instruction for another software (version) or I got you wrong let me know.